# How this dict comprehension works in this program?

Tags: python

Help to understand dict comprehension
sort dict by the value

```
   aDict = {'Maharashtra': 4238,
     'Delhi': 2003,
     'Gujarat': 1743,
     'Rajasthan': 1478,
     'Tamil Nadu': 1477}
    sorted_dict = {k:v for k,v in sorted(aDict.items(), key= lambda item:items[1])}
```

Comment: What specifically about it are you asking about?

Comment: btw there is an error in your code. Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the idea behind the code is to produce a `sorted dictionary`.

This is not normally a thing in python, except in recent versions the `dict` type has changed to hold items in the order in which they were added.

The `dict` comprehension is adding items from `aDict` in the order of the values, so the comprehension will keep this order.

The idea of the code is that it produces `sorted_dict` with the value:

```
{'Tamil Nadu': 1477, 'Rajasthan': 1478, 'Gujarat': 1743, 'Delhi': 2003, 'Maharashtra': 4238}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i'm correct, idea of this code is creation of sorted_dict by value, but there is some problem:

`key= lambda item:items[1]` items in lambda is not defined, so python will raise exception.

Idea:

1) sorted function will return list of tuples `(key, value)` sorted by values from smallest to biggest

`[('Tamil Nadu', 1477), ('Rajasthan', 1478), ('Gujarat', 1743), ('Delhi', 2003), ('Maharashtra', 4238)]`

2) Dict comprehension will create a dictionary with ascending order

`{'Tamil Nadu': 1477, 'Rajasthan': 1478, 'Gujarat': 1743, 'Delhi': 2003, 'Maharashtra': 4238}`

What i can suggest is using OrderedDict if you care about order in dictionary